# Pass IP into VNC Viewer

Tags: powershell, server, command-line-arguments, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to use VNC Viewer and pass in the server IP I need it to use. The trouble is I can't figure out the syntax of the `-ArgumentList` to do it properly.

```
Start-Process -Filepath "VNCViewer\viewer.exe" -ArgumentList "<hostname>=<$IP>"
```

Comment: `-ArgumentList $IP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [vncviewer documentation](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/man/vncviewer.html) lists the syntax as

> `vncviewer snoopy` connects to display 0 on ‘snoopy’

So in your case, you would pass the computer name (IP) as the only argument... like this:

```
$IP = "192.168.1.1"
Start-Process -Filepath "VNCViewer\viewer.exe" -ArgumentList $IP
```